# Reusable workflows with local actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Reusable workflows with local actions are not working. Reusable workflow is trying to locate the local action in the main repo

Created sample repositories to reproduce the issue

1. Repo with reusable workflows and local action - https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-reusable-workflow-sample
2. Sample repo which uses above reusable workflows - https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-example-repo

This is the PR link -> https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-example-repo/pull/1

Error -> https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-example-repo/pull/1/checks

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Update: you can use below workaround on github.com and GHE Server v3.9+ without the input 'workflows-ref' and instead use `github.workflow_ref` ([doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)) or the env-var `GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF` ([doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables)). thanks [@Philip Couling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453851/philip-couling)

There is a workaround, it comes however with the downside of needing to specify the ref for the reusable workflow twice, like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-push:
    uses: <org>/<central-workflow-repo>/.github/workflows/build-push.yml@v1.2 # always change with.workflows-ref, too
    with:
      workflows-ref: v1.2
    secrets:
      # can't use GITHUB_TOKEN as its different repo
      GH_ACCESSTOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_ACCESSTOKEN }}
```

The repo of your reusable workflow has this structure:

```
<org>/<central-workflow-repo>/ (github repo)
├─ .github/
│  ├─ workflows/
│  │  ├─ build-push.yml
├─ actions/
│  ├─ your-action/
│  │  ├─ action.yml
```

1. Check-out the repo of the called workflow to `workflows`

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      workflows-ref:
        description: "ref of the centralized workflows repo that was specified in 'jobs.<name>.uses'"
        required: true
        type: string
...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout workflows repo # required so we can reference the actions locally
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ inputs.workflows-ref }}
          path: workflows
          repository: <org>/<central-workflow-repo>
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_ACCESSTOKEN }}
```

2. (optional) if you want your calling repo checked out, do so, but to a subdirectory

```yaml
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: app
```

3. Start referencing your local actions:

```yaml
      - uses: ./workflows/actions/your-action
```

Comment: Can you given an example on how you use the github.workflow_ref or GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF. I tried that, but it points to the original workflow ref (e.g. caller-repo/.github/workflows/caller.yml@refs/pull/23/merge) and not the called one (e.g. ...@v1.2).

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is that you can't call a local action on a repository without using the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action to access the files in the repository.

```yaml
on: [workflow_call]

jobs:
  local-action-testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4 # Necessary to access local action
      - uses: ./actions/local-action
```

I've got some proofs of concept here if you want to take a look:

- [local action workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/36-local-action.yml) and [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5124912354?check_suite_focus=true)
- [reusable workflow using a local action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/33-reusable-workflow.yml), triggered by this [workflow call](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/34-workflow-call.yml), performing this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5124877327?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: In your case, both are in a single repository. The error is when the reusable workflow is in one repo and the caller is in another repo. I have added actions/checkout, it is still having the same issue
https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-reusable-workflow-sample/pull/1/files
https://github.com/vinodsai-a/github-example-repo/pull/2/checks

Comment: `/home/runner/work/github-example-repo/github-example-repo/actions/local-action` path where it is checking is wrong. It should check in github-reusable-workflow-sample but it is checking in github-example-repo

Comment: I used the checkout@v3
and I got an error
I change the code to this path ./.github/actions/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think as of now GitHub allows any way to use actions from reusable workflow repo. Currently. reusable workflow functionality is very limited and all the actions in the reusable workflow run as part of the caller workflow. So when you are specifying to run action in path `./actions/local-action` GitHub action is trying to find the action in your caller repo and since the path isn't valid for caller repo you are getting the error.

The current workaround is treat your action as if it is hosted in external repo instead of local path as [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses).
In your case you can specify `vinodsai-a/github-reusable-workflow-sample/actions/local-action@main` instead of `./actions/local-action`.

Comment: Using "main" will not necessarily use the right branch of the repo to reference the action

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible at this point in time. You may consider posting your query at https://github.community/c/code-to-cloud/52 to get better visibility to this request.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue.

When using local actions they need to be placed at the job level (NOT inside the steps of a job). Your caller action should be changed from:

```
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  ci:
    uses: vinodsai-a/github-reusable-workflow-sample/.github/workflows/main.yml@main
```

to:

```
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  uses: vinodsai-a/github-reusable-workflow-sample/.github/workflows/main.yml@main
```

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Even the documentation you referred to shows that the call has to be within a job. In the above documentation, the 3 jobs where the calls are made, are named `call-workflow-1-in-local-repo`, `call-workflow-2-in-local-repo` and `call-workflow-in-another-repo`.